# Reporting Services On-Prem Usage Tracking

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi

I would like to track the usage of SSRS and Power BI reports that live on a on-prem server. The app service provides these metrics but the on-prem version sits on SQL Server so you must use the ExecutionLog3 table.

The table is more difficult to query for PBIX reports as it's not straight forward what a true "usage" is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to write this but it gets you pretty close to tracking on-prem usage of all your reports - SSRS and Power BI

```
declare @results TABLE
(
    Report  NVARCHAR(50),
    ExecutionTime DATETIME,
    UserName NVARCHAR(25),
    ExecutionId NVARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO @results 
SELECT
       Name,
       TimeStart,
       UserName,
       ExecutionId
  FROM (SELECT TimeStart,
               Catalog.Name,
               UserName,
               ExecutionId
          FROM Catalog
               INNER JOIN 
               ExecutionLog3
                 ON Catalog.Path = ExecutionLog3.ItemPath
         WHERE Type IN (2) --ssrs
       ) AS RE
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       Name,
       TimeStart,
        UserName,
        ExecutionId
  FROM (SELECT  TimeStart,
               Catalog.Type,
               Catalog.Name,
                UserName,
                ExecutionId
          FROM Catalog
               INNER JOIN 
               ExecutionLog3
                 ON Catalog.Path = ExecutionLog3.ItemPath
         WHERE Type IN (13) --power BI
         AND ItemAction = 'ConceptualSchema'
         AND Format = 'PBIX'
       ) AS RE
       Order By TimeStart DESC

;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ExecutionId ORDER BY ExecutionTime DESC) AS rn
   FROM @results
)
SELECT
Report,
ExecutionTime,
UserName
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ExecutionTime DESC
```